# Execute Cucumber crontab

Tags: shell, jar, cucumber, cron

I want to execute cucumber in my computer.
in terminal I can execute cucumber ( cucumber feature )
and I can using crontab
but, I can't crontab execute shell script, shell script execute jar, jar execute cucumber in my environment

Comment: Show some of your attempts. I would basically suggest to make a try with `* * * * * /path/to/cucumber /file/to/execu.te`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script to invoke cucumber command, like this:

/home/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd your_work_directory
cucumber -p test
```

Then execute 'crontab -e' command to edit your cron job, because crontab shell is not login-shell, so you need code like this:

```
0 1 * * * bash -lc '/home/test.sh'
```

If your cucumber need GUI environment, your code should be like this:

```
0 1 * * * env DISPLAY=:0 bash -lc '/home/test.sh'
```